# Convert date to datetime or timestamp using alter table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql with DATE column, now I need to convert these values to DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.

I wonder what will happen with data when I'll do:

```
ALTER TABLE sample MODIFY sample_date DATETIME
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE sample MODIFY sample_date TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward to convert from one type to another using the ALTER TABLE command:

`ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE old_date new_timestamp TIMESTAMP`
This process may take a while to complete if you have a lot of data and a large number of indexes.

I'm not sure why you'd want to switch these to the TIMESTAMP type as that has a much more limited range than DATETIME. The differences are documented and important to know.